# Elasticsearch query serialization returns empty string

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I want to extract the JSON representation of an Elasticsearch Query, which was built by the Java client API (Java API Client 8.0.0). The following code shows my try:

```
    Query x1 = new Query(new TermQuery.Builder().field("f1").value(v -> v.stringValue("val1")).build());
    Query x2 = new Query(new TermQuery.Builder().field("f2").value(v -> v.stringValue("val2")).build());
    Query query = new Query(new BoolQuery.Builder().must(List.of(x1, x2)).build());

    try (final var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        final JsonGenerator generator = Json.createGenerator(out);
        query.serialize(generator, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
        return out.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

I'm using the `org.glassfish.jakarta-json:2.0.1` package to provide the `JsonGenerator` implementation.

The returned string is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late but if anyone is still looking, you need to close the `JsonGenerator` and then you will have the JSON output.

Comment: Had the same type of problem, only my symptom was that the JSON string terminated too early.  I put the `JsonGenerator` instantiation in a try so it would close and it worked like a charm!